# Grails with SpringSecurity, check if the current user can access controller / action

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm currently developing a menu for my application that should be able to display only the controllers that the current user can access (requestmap defined in the database).

How can I check if the current user has access to a specific controller and action?

Answer (score 7):

To check roles in view :
  Spring security plugin provides ifAllGranted, ifAnyGranted, ifNoneGranted etc., tags to check roles

For example, to check Admin Role of logged in User :

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
    <sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
        Admin resource
     </sec:ifAllGranted>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

(tested in grails-2.2.2 and springSecurityCorePlugin-1.2.7.3)

Comment: ...and then there's `<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN">`, too

Answer (score 4):

```
org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService authenticateService = new org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService()
def isAdmin = authenticateService.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')

if(isAdmin) {
   println 'I am Admin'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty old, but I thought I'd post at least an answer that seems to work with Grails 2.0. If you are using the spring security plugin, there's a tag lib included called *grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityTagLib*.

The tag-lib has a protected method, hasAccess() which can take the same params map that you give the *g:link* tag. So, if you extend SecurityTagLib, you can call hasAccess() and get the behavior you want. Why this isn't externalized into a service that can be injected is beyond me as the functionality seems to fulfill an obvious need.

We use this to wrap the *g:link* tag and only generate a link of the user has access to the target page:

```
def link = { attrs, body ->
    if( hasAccess(attrs.clone(), "link") ) {
        out << g.link(attrs, body)
    }
    else {
        out << body()
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping g:link is also what we did. BTW Groovy disregards `protected` and even `private`, so you just can inject an instance of `SecurityTagLib` and invoke it.

Comment: I am not sure of the situation when this was answered, but this functionality is now exposed through 'SpringSecurityUtils`.

Comment: @mattforsythe where exactly is it exposed? Neither the [docs](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityUtils) nor the [source code](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils.java) mention any method that can accept a map with `controller` and `action` (or `url`) arguments and return a boolean, which is what `hasAccess()` does.

Comment: @Tobia Hmmm.... you seem to be right.  I'm not sure what I was looking at a year ago when I wrote that comment.  But it does look like the `<sec:access>` will do this for you.  But that assumes you are inside a GSP and in Groovy code.

Comment: @Victor Sergienko Great advice! I used ```SecurityTagLib securityTagLib = (SecurityTagLib)Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityTagLib')``` to inject it!

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with permissions in views and taglibs, you can use the [AuthorizeTagLib](http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Artifacts) that's provided by the plugin.

For example, if you don't want a menu item to appear in your list for unauthenticated users, you might use:

```
<g:isLoggedIn>
  <li>Restricted Link</li>
</g:isLoggedIn>
```

If you have more specific roles defined and those roles are tied to your controller/action request mapping, you can use other tags, such as:

```
<g:ifAllGranted role="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
  <li>Administrator Link</li>
</g:ifAllGranted>
```

In my experience, there's not yet a good way to tie the request mapping to your markup - I think you're going to have to use some of the above tags to limit access to content within a particular GSP.

I think that Burt Beckwith has a future modification (and is currently providing a [beta version](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=287)) to the plugin that integrates some ACL stuff that might solve this problem better in the future, but for now, I think the best approach is a hybrid request map + GSP tags one.

Comment: I've seen that TagLib, but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Maybe I could use the ifAllGranted or ifAnyGranted methods, if there is a way to match a controller and action to an entry in my RequestMap... Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the situation when this question was originally asked, but now you can check to see if a user is in a specific role by using `SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted()` which takes a single String which is a comma delimited list of roles.  It will return true if the current user belongs to all of them.

```
if(SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER')) {
```

Obviously, you can simply pass one role to the function if that is all you need.  `SpringSecurityUtils` also has methods like `ifAnyGranted`, `ifNotGranted`, etc, so it should work for whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

`SpringSecurityUtils` is a static API, so you don't need to create a private member named `springSecurityUtils` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the file config/SecurityConfig.groovy (if it does not exists, create it, this overrides the default Security Configuration)

Add this entry:

```
requestMapString = """\
            CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
            PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
            /=IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
            /login/auth=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /login/authajax=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /login/authfail=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY 
            /js/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /css/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /images/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /plugins/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
          """
```

This is means that you have to log in to enter the site. But all the resources (css, js, images, etc) is accessed without authentification.

If you want specific role only enter specific controller:
For example, for UserController:

```
    /user/**=ROLE_ADMIN
    /role/**=ROLE_ADMIN
```

For more information: http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Securing+URLs

Regards

Comment: Sorry if my question was misunderstanding, I have already secured my controllers with a RequestMap (not in the SecurityConfig.groovy, but using a database table) and all this works perfect.

My question was, how can I check if the current user has access to a certain controller and action.

I'm thinking of it like this:

    if (currentUserHasAccess(controller, action)) { do_some_stuff }

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there doesn't look like there's an easy way to do it.

You can inject an instance of the grails AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager which is a concrete class of spring's AbstractAccessDecisionManager by doing this:

```
def accessDecisionManager
```

This has a "decide" method on it that takes 3 parameters

```
decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, ConfigAttributeDefinition config)
```

This is probably the method that you'd need to call and pass in the right things to figure out if the user with the auth creds can access that "object" (which looks like it's normally a request/response).  Some additional digging around might prove out something workable here.

Short term, it's probably easier to use the ifAnyGranted taglib as another poster mentions.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll look for a solution in this direction. Anyway, I'd like to use the ifAnyGranted taglib, but then I still need to figure out which roles apply in the current case, that means, finding a way to get the roles for a specific controller/action out of my RequestMap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about in Groovy, but in Java (so I assume Groovy too...) you could do (minus NPE checks):

```
GrantedAuthority[] authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
boolean isAdmin = false;
for(GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
    String role = authority.getAuthority();
    if(role != null && role.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        isAdmin = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

As for knowing whether or not the action is supported, you'd have to call the RequestMap service to get the roles for the mapping and see if it contains the found user role.

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I think this is what ifAnyGranted does... The interesting Part ist this "RequestMap Service" -- do you have more information about it? I couldn't find anything with google...