# Grails check role access for specific controller action

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, user-permissions, user-roles

I need to display/hide action buttons depending if the user can access (by role definition) the specific controller/action.  I'm using Spring Security plugin.

My goal is to used the annotation @Secured("ROLE_...") for every method of each of my controller and I'm looking for a way to check, before calling the action, if the user has access to this specific action.  I'm guessing there is way to check this because the annotation brings the information but I cannot find any solution.

In this example I'm trying to find the HASACCESS method:

The controller with the @Secured annotation

```
    class MyExampleController{

      @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
      def myMethod(){ do stuff.. }

    }
```

The HTML code to include de link

```
    <role:link controller="myExample" action="myMethod">Action</role:link>
```

And my tagLib role

```
    class RoleTagLib {
     static namespace = "role"

      def link = {attrs, body ->
        User user = (User) springSecurityService.currentUser          
        if(HASACCESS(user, attrs.controller, attrs.action)){
          out << g.link(attrs, body)
        }
      }
    }
```

I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306492/grails-with-springsecurity-check-if-the-current-user-can-access-controller-ac) the "hasAccess()" method contained into the SecurityTagLib but this method is protected and even when I extend the SecurityTagLib with mine the call of this method returns me "No signature of method...".  I think it uses the interceptUrlMap defined in Config.groovy and not the annotations anyway.

EDIT: I succeed to extend the security tagLib and use the "hasAccess" method but it seems that it uses only the interceptUrlMap contained in Config.groovy and doesn't care about the annotations I put in my controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.  The method "hasAccess" in SecurityTagLib is based on **grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType** in Config.groovy.  My initial value was **SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap** and then I would have defined every url accessible and specify which role can access each of them manually in the **grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap**

The solution is to change this to **SecurityConfigType.Annotation** and modify *interceptUrlMap* to *staticRules*.  Then the method "hasAccess" is based on the annotations defined in the controller and can hide properly the content with my tagLib wrapped from SecurityTagLib.

There is the code in Config.groovy

```
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Annotation
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.staticRules = [
      ... your rules ... for example:
      '/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN_ACCESS'] 
    ]
```

The code of my tagLib

```
    class RoleTagLib extends SecurityTagLib {

        static namespace = "role"

        def link = { attrs, body ->
            if (hasAccess(attrs.clone(), "link")) {
                out << g.link(attrs, body)
            }
        }
    }
```

And I use this to show or hide any link in my .gsp files based on the @Secured annotation put for every action of every controller

```
    <role:link controller="myController" action="myAction">
      Action
    </role:link>
```

Comment: If you use the namespace `sec.` then you don't need to extend SecurityTagLib. `if (sec.hasAccess(attrs.clone(), "true")) {...}` It works for me, at least. Also, using the string `true` makes it clear that any non-empty string would do.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
  secure stuff here
</sec:ifAllGranted>
```

or

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
    secure stuff here
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```

according the [Spring Security Core Grails plugin documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib).

Or simply use the Spring security core taglib with your tag library.

```
class RoleTagLib {
  static namespace = "role"

  SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

  def link = { attrs, body ->
    User user = (User) springSecurityService.currentUser          
    sec.ifAnyGranted(roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR'){
      out << g.link(attrs, body)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the SecurityTagLib brings this way to check the role but I try to find a more "central" and light way to adapt my .gsp files.  Instead of put these tests everywhere for every g:link tag, I would like to simply replace g:link by my role:link.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So have you tried to simply wrap the spring security taglib?

Comment: Yes I've tried (according the to the other thread I mentionned in my post) but I couldn't succeed.  It seems that the "hasAccess" method in security tagLib use the interceptUrlMap defined in Config.groovy and not the annotation because the sec:ifAnyGranted works by blocking access and the "hasAccess" method grant access it is suppose to block... It would force me to define, url by url, every access allowed for every specific role.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Grails 2.3

To check action access from another controller or service, do this:

```
@Secured(["ONE_OF_MY_ROLES"])
class SomeController {

    SecurityTagLib securityTagLib = (SecurityTagLib)Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityTagLib')

    def show() {
        def access = securityTagLib.hasAccess([controller: 'product', action: 'show'], 'access')
    }
}
```