# Grails check role access for specific controller action from groovy

Tags: grails, spring-security

This is basically the same question as here [Grails check role access for specific controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549160/grails-check-role-access-for-specific-controller-action) except that I want to check access for a Grails action from within another controller or service, not from GSP.

This is very useful when you want to use action access to determine access instead of roles directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Grails 2.3

```
@Secured(["ONE_OF_MY_ROLES"])
class SomeController {

    SecurityTagLib securityTagLib = (SecurityTagLib)Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityTagLib')

    def show() {
        def access = securityTagLib.hasAccess([controller: 'product', action: 'show'], 'access')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured 

@Secured(['ROLE_USER']) // @Secured to the selected role by ([role that you want])
    def followAjax = { ... } // controller
```

About should be working. *Remember to "import Secured" before calling @Secured.